# Change button android:background to different drawable

Tags: android, button, background, drawable

I am new to Android and Java but have managed to teach myself and find most answers to questions on stackoverflow without needing to ask questions.  Until now....

Here goes, I have many colored buttons which, when clicked, change color to a range of different colors.

There are many buttons defined for example as:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button17"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@drawable/orange_button"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Could someone please advise me how to change the android:background using code to change the above example to yellow, for example, when the button is clicked.

In the code below clickedButton is the ID of the button for which I need to change the background.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id=v.getId();
    String clickedButton = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    Change button to Yellow here??

    // Temporary code below to check which button was pressed
    // and convert its number to an integer to eventually access an array

    final TextView tvGameTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGameTimer);
    int buttonNumber = Integer.parseInt(clickedButton.substring(6,8));
    tvGameTimer.setText("" + buttonNumber);

    }
```

I am using custom button styles to define the button colors:

```
res/drawable/yellow_button.xml
res/drawable/blue_button.xml
res/drawable/red_button.xml
res/drawable/orange_button.xml
res/drawable/green_button.xml
```

For now I just need to work out how to change the button from Orange to Yellow. I can then add the logic to change the colors as and when the app requires.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am supposing that the onClick method you post is of the same Button whose background you are trying to change. Use this code.

```
  v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_button);
```

If onClick is not the method of the same button then, use

```
  findViewById(R.id.button17).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_button);
```

Comment: Wow.  What a community!  Spot on.  The onClick method is on the same Button I need to change so your first solution worked first time.   Now all the buttons turn yellow if clicked!  I can now press on with the logic.  Thanks.

Comment: When I leave the activity to another activity and return to the first one the background doesn't revert back to the original drawable.

Comment: @SiKni8 for the effect you want, you should use <selector>

Answer (score 2):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
btn.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow_button));
```

Try this.

Comment: The method getDrawable(int) from the type Resources is deprecated.