# How to make Listview Like Skype In android. Change Object Design Runtime In Adapter. (Please Check Screen Shot)

Tags: android

> Basically I want

1. First msg design like - Top Corner border with open bottom
2. Second or middle msg design like -  square box with an open bottom and Top borders
3. Last Msg design - Bottom Corner border with Top open

```
> //Adapter BindViewHolder Code
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final RealmChatModel chatModel = getItem(position); // Current position Msg
    final RealmChatModel previousChatModel = getItem(position-1); //Previous position Msg
    final RealmChatModel nextChatModel = getItem(position+1); //Nextposition Msg

    if (chatModel.getUserId().equals(nextChatModel.getUserId())) {
          holder.left_profile_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          Log.e("Shape","Bottam");
     } else if (chatModel.getUserId().equals(previousChatModel.getUserId()){
                    holder.left_profile_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   Log.e("Shape","Top");
     }
     if (chatModel.getUserId().equals(nextChatModel.getUserId())
             && chatModel.getUserId().equals(previousChatModel.getUserId())
              && chatDateString.equals(nextDateString)) {
                                holder.left_profile_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                 Log.e("Shape","Middle");
                                }
  }
```

[Image Here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1365.jpg)

Comment: in your adapter,if the previous message.userId != current userId -> show the avatar image and set as userAvatar, else set it invisible

Comment: and use recyclerview instead btw

Comment: I have done this. but not able to shape properly. Top, Middle, Bottom

Comment: basically, you just need change the backgroundDrawable if you check your logic is right,and no need to show hide follow to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989906/change-button-androidbackground-to-different-drawable) link

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using multiple view holders.

check [this example](https://github.com/NAndroidEx/Sticky-Header-RecyclerView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nandroidex/demostickyheaderrecyclerview/DummyAdapter.kt) to know more about how to set multiple view holders for single RecyclerView.

**OR**

You can do it using different background drawable as per your conditions.